# python GUI countdown timer (don't use classes)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, timer, countdown

i have just one problem in my source code, lbl_time will not change, all thing running well except this.
I could only use function in my program, if someone can help me in this functional program, please do it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import timedelta
import winsound
```

set time is a function that for counting down time, i use timedelta for building a time object to simple operation

```
def main():
    def set_time(hours:int=0, minutes:int=0, seconds:int=0):
        end = timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
        one_second = timedelta(seconds=1)
        result = end - one_second
        new_time = seconds_to_hms(result.seconds)
        if result.seconds is 0:
            while True:
                try:
                    winsound.PlaySound("Ringtones\\1.cookie clock.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    break
        else:
            hours, minutes, seconds = new_time.get('hours'), new_time.get('minutes'), new_time.get('seconds')
            time.set(str(hours)+':'+str(minutes)+':'+str(seconds))
            root.update()
            root.after(1000, lambda : set_time(hours, minutes, seconds))

    def seconds_to_hms(seconds:int) -> dict:
        hours, minutes, seconds = 0, 0, seconds
        if seconds >= 3600:
            hours = seconds//3600
            seconds = seconds - hours*3600
        if seconds >= 60:
            minutes = seconds//60
            seconds = seconds - minutes*60
        result = {'hours': hours, 'minutes': minutes, 'seconds': seconds}
        return result

    def quit(*args):
        root.destroy()

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title(string='Timer')
    time = tk.StringVar()
    root.configure(background='black')
    logo = tk.PhotoImage(file='Logo.png')
    lbl_logo = tk.Label(root, image=logo, bg='black').pack(side='right')
    lbl_timer = tk.Label(root, padx=10, text="Timer", fg='white', bg='black', font='Times 24', anchor='center').pack()
    lbl_time = tk.Label(root, text=time, font="Times 38", fg='white', bg='black').pack()
    btn_start = tk.Button(root, text='start', bg='gray', fg='black', command=lambda : set_time()).pack()
    root.bind('x', quit)
    root.after(1000, lambda : set_time(0,0, 3))
    root.mainloop()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the restriction. Why can you not use classes? I'm not saying that the natural solution requires classes, but you're hinting at a restriction we know nothing about.

Comment: @roganjosh because this is a practice and said that dont use classes bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took some time to understand your question, but I might have solved your problem.

1. Fundamentally you ought to have used `textvariable` rather than `text` as an argument in your `lbl_time` declaration.
2. If your `while loop` is executed, it might result in an infinite loop, you might want to have an increment if the code branches there.

Do check out the following, you might want to uncomment some of the lines, hopefully it does solve your problem:

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import timedelta
import winsound
def main():
    def set_time(hours:int=0, minutes:int=0, seconds:int=0):
        end = timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
        one_second = timedelta(seconds=1)
        result = end - one_second
        new_time = seconds_to_hms(result.seconds)
        if result.seconds is 0:
            while True:
                try:
                    winsound.PlaySound("Ringtones\\1.cookie clock.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    break
        else:
            hours, minutes, seconds = new_time.get('hours'), new_time.get('minutes'), new_time.get('seconds')
            time.set(str(hours)+':'+str(minutes)+':'+str(seconds))
            root.update()
            root.after(1000, lambda : set_time(hours, minutes, seconds))

    def seconds_to_hms(seconds:int) -> dict:
        hours, minutes, seconds = 0, 0, seconds
        if seconds >= 3600:
            hours = seconds//3600
            seconds = seconds - hours*3600
        if seconds >= 60:
            minutes = seconds//60
            seconds = seconds - minutes*60
        result = {'hours': hours, 'minutes': minutes, 'seconds': seconds}
        return result

    def quit(*args):
        root.destroy()

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title(string='Timer')
    time = tk.StringVar()
    root.configure(background='black')
  #  logo = tk.PhotoImage(file='Logo.png')
  #  lbl_logo = tk.Label(root, image=logo, bg='black').pack(side='right')
    lbl_timer = tk.Label(root, padx=10, text="Timer", fg='white', bg='black', font='Times 24', anchor='center').pack()
    lbl_time = tk.Label(root, textvariable=time, font="Times 38", fg='white', bg='black').pack() #changed text to textvariable
    btn_start = tk.Button(root, text='start', bg='gray', fg='black', command=lambda :set_time(0,0,3700)).pack()
    root.bind('x', quit)
    #root.after(1000, lambda : set_time(0,0, 3))
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```